# Bootstrap menu error in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I noticed that my mobile bootstrap template when you open the navigation bar and select an item the bar does not hide automatically.

I would like that clicking on an item in the navigation bar on my landing page would automatically hide the navbar.

This is the navbar code:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- Logo -->
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                    <a class="logo" href="index.html">
                        <img class="logo-img" src="./img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                        <img class="logo-alt-img" src="./img/logo-alt.png" alt="logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /Logo -->

                <!-- Mobile toggle -->
                <button class="navbar-toggle">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                <!-- /Mobile toggle -->
            </div>
            <!-- /navbar header -->

            <!-- Navigation -->
            <nav id="nav">
                <ul class="main-nav nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#page0">Page 0</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page4">Page 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page5">Page 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page6">Page 6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- /Navigation -->
        </div>
```

I do not know how to do it because I'm not very experienced in this field so I do not know where to start

Comment: Could you create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/bootstrap) with your code please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/91289/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your smoothscroll function you can trigger the toggle event.

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/9gh0q2o3/

**JS**:

```
$(".main-nav a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.main-nav').toggleClass('open');   <== HERE
    var hash = this.hash;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 800);
});
```